# Java Hibernate returns null result

Tags: java, hibernate, resultset

I am working on an update for an existing web application.  I have written some classes to create a table and add/remove data.  For some reason, I can insert data but I cannot retrieve results even though there is data in the table.  I have created a test class using the same code that does return results.  However, when calling my class as a service, the resultSet is null every time.  Also note that I can pull data from some of the other existing tables using my code, just not from the table/Object I created.  In addition, I have taken the SQL query from the debugger and ran it against the database, and get results.

Here is the code:

```
public DiscountCode getDiscountCodeDetails(String code) {

    Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    String query = "from DiscountCode where isActive = 1 and discountCode = :replace";
    **DiscountCode discountCode** =  (DiscountCode) session.createQuery(query).setParameter("replace", code).uniqueResult();
    transaction.commit();
    session.close();

    return discountCode;
}
```

discountCode is always NULL.

This test code works in a simple class with a main:
    String replace = "TEXT10";

```
    Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    String query = "from DiscountCode where isActive = 1 and discountCode = :replace";
    DiscountCode discountCode =  (DiscountCode) session.createQuery(query).setParameter("replace", replace).uniqueResult();

    transaction.commit();
    session.close();
    System.out.println(discountCode.getDiscountCodeName());
```

I have been fighting this for a good while and need to get past this asap.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that code is what you think it is?

Comment: If you've just created the table using hibernate, doesn't the database need to be refreshed or doesn't hibernate need to be informed that there's a new table in the database? Might be cache related problem or so...

Comment: OK, I have found the problem.  It has to do with what is being passed to the method.  I hardcoded the variable "code" to a known good value and get results I am looking for.  In the Eclipse debugger, I see the value of code is {"code":"text10"} (an Object?).  I do not get why this would be an object as opposed to a String.

Comment: Kayaman, Your answer is correct.  Make your comment an answer and I will mark it correct.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: What was the problem? I'm having an [issue that might be similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367765/why-do-i-have-to-open-a-second-session-to-get-this-database-entry).

Comment: @Lenymm Any idea how to fix [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367765/why-do-i-have-to-open-a-second-session-to-get-this-database-entry)?