# Hibernate: Strange behavior - second commit() in another session needed to access table entry

Tags: hibernate

I'm having an abstract class that just provides simple access to session-creation:

```
private Session currentSession = null;
private Transaction currentTransaction = null;

protected void openSession() {
    this.currentSession = HibernateSession.openSession();
}

protected void openSessionWithTransaction() {
    this.currentSession = HibernateSession.openSession();
    this.currentTransaction = this.currentSession.beginTransaction();
}

public void closeSessionWithTransaction() { 
    this.currentTransaction.commit();
    this.currentSession.close();
}
```

I have noticed that when I try to retrieve an entry

```
Tool tool = (Tool) this.getSession().get(Tool.class, toolDto.getId());
```

I have to call `commit()` first (on a session that has nothing to do with the transaction before or after it) even though the given ID (here given by `toolDto.getId()` **does exist**. I can see it in the database but `get()` keeps returning `null` *unless* I call `commit()` again:

This is what happens first:

```
HammerDTO hammerDto = toolSetDto.getHammer();
Hammer hammer = null;

if(hammerDto != null) {
    ToolDTO toolDto = hammerDto.getTool();
    ToolDescriptionDTO hammerDescriptionDto = toolDto.getToolDescription(languageDto.getId());
    // Save new tool
    ToolDescriptionDTO toolDescriptionDto = toolDescriptionRepository.save(storeDto, languageDto, toolDto, hammerDescriptionDto);

    HammerRepository hammerRepository = new HammerRepository(this.getSessionId());
    // Merge new tool into list of (in this case) hammers
    hammer = hammerRepository.merge(storeDto, toolDescriptionDto.getToolDto());
}
```

I am storing the new tool and its description. **This part works and the `Tool` entry as well as the `ToolDescription` entry are present after this:

```
public ToolDescriptionDTO save(StoreDTO storeDto, LanguageDTO languageDto, ToolDTO toolDto, ToolDescriptionDTO toolDescriptionDto) {

    if(toolDto == null) {
        throw new NullArgumentException("toolDto");
    }

    if(toolDescriptionDto == null) {
        throw new NullArgumentException("toolDescriptionDto");
    }

    this.openSessionWithTransaction();

    Tool tool = null;
    ToolDescription toolDescription = null;

    // First try to check if description exists if it does: load it otherwise: create new one

    Long toolDescriptionId = toolDescriptionDto.getId();

    if(toolDescriptionId != null) {
        toolDescription = (ToolDescription) this.getSession().get(ToolDescription.class, toolDescriptionId);
        tool = toolDescription.getTool();
    }

    if(tool == null) {

        Language language = (Language) this.getSession().get(Language.class, languageDto.getId());

        Store store = this.getStore(storeDto.getId());

        tool = new Tool(store);
        ConvertDTO.convertTool(tool, toolDto);

        tool = (Tool) this.getSession().merge(tool);
        toolDescription = new ToolDescription(tool, language);
    }


    ConvertDTO.convertToolDescription(toolDescription, toolDescriptionDto);
    this.getSession().merge(toolDescription);

    toolDescriptionDto = ConvertEntity.convertToolDescription(toolDescription);

    this.closeSessionWithTransaction();

    return toolDescriptionDto;
}
```

and here is the part that stops working as I would expect it. Trying to add the "*Hammer*" to the list of hammers it only works with an imho completely unrelated call on `commit()` on a imho completely unrelated session:

```
public Hammer merge(ToolStoreDTO toolStoreDto, ToolDTO toolDto) {

    this.openSession();

    Criteria cr = this.getSession().createCriteria(Hammer.class);
    cr.add(Restrictions.eq("toolStore.id", toolStoreDto.getId()));
    cr.add(Restrictions.eq("tool.id", toolDto.getId()));

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Hammer> hammers = cr.list();
    Hammer hammer = null;

    // IT ONLY WORKS WITH THIS COMMIT!
    this.getSession().beginTransaction().commit(); // <----- ??

    this.closeSession();

    if(hammers.isEmpty() == false) {
        hammer = hammers.get(0);
    } else {
        ToolStore toolStore = this.getToolStore(toolStoreDto.getId());

        this.openSessionWithTransaction();

        // Always 'null' if the commit above is not executed!
        Tool tool = (Tool) this.getSession().get(Tool.class, toolDto.getId());

        hammer = new Tool(toolStore, tool);
        hammer = (Hammer) this.getSession().merge(tool);

        this.closeSessionWithTransaction();
    }

    return hammer;
}
```

This does not make sense to me. **I have already committed** (in a previous session) **and the according entry does exist**.

What could be the reason for this behavior?

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mahlzeit_db</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="format_sql">false</property>            
        <!-- Run Hibernate in update mode -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>        
        <!-- ... --->
    </session-factory>  
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: can you show the code of `this.closeSessionWithTransaction()`?

Comment: first thing I like mention here that there is no need to `beginTransaction` for `select` query. you can just open a session use `criteria API` or `HQL` to fetch the records and close the session. Why your are opening transaction?

Comment: My primary guess is you haven't called `session.flush()` (considering Flush Mode setting of hibernate is changed) when you are inserting data in DB and committing the transaction.

Comment: @Amogh I have added the function but it jus calles commit() on the transaction and close() on the session. I am opening a transaction for `this.getSession().merge(tool);` - I think there I need `beginTransaction()`, right? Please don't get confused here: The method above is just supposed to load an already existing object from the entity `Tool`. Flushing the session did not help either. The session that stored the tool object I am accessing here was closed in another object.

Comment: are you sure that the object or the id (toolDto.getId()) is present in DB at the time of `Tool tool = (Tool) this.getSession().get(Tool.class, toolDto.getId());` if yes then could you post your hibernate configuration.

Comment: @Amogh Yes, I am 100% sure. I can see in phpMyAdmin that the Tool entry gets created. In debug mode I can see that the correct ID gets queried. I don't have the config right here I can post it tomorrow but hibernate is not `hdm2ddl.auto` is set to `update` - not create as you might suspect.

Comment: Ok. Here i generated the scenario matching to you but i am getting data even if i don't commit before get(). I suggest you tomorrow please post config and query output by setting show_sql to true. Regards and thanks.

Comment: @Amogh I have added more code and my `hibernate.cfg.xml` - hope that helps ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83105/discussion-between-amogh-and-stefan-falk).