# Am I using Hibernate-Sessions wrong?

Tags: hibernate

Right now I'm asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367765/hibernate-strange-behavior-second-commit-in-another-session-needed-to-acces) on stack**overflow** and [that one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/96615/hibernate-and-the-repository-pattern) on codereview.

This makes me thinking if I have understood how to use Hibernate sessions. I'll try to make this short:

Assume you have Tools and Descriptions of Tools in multiple Languages. Therefore you have `Tool`, `ToolDescription` and `Language` tables. Now further assume you give a client the possibility to put together a set of tools but not only for existing ones, he can also create new ones by just inventing a new name. As the client sends the data to the server, it tries to store the set of tools but has to save the new ones first. It would look like this:

Client sends:

```
ToolSet
  id:1
    Tool1
      id:2
        en:"My Hammer"
        de:"Mein Hammer"
    Tool2
      id:null
        en:"My new Tool"
        de:"Mein neues Werkzeug"
```

To save this one would have to do something like this: (note that one of the tools does not have an ID).

```
toolSet = getToolSet(toolSetDto.getId());

if(toolSetDto.tool1 != null) {
    tool1Dto = toolDescriptionRepository.updateOrSaveNewTool(toolSetDto.getTool1());
}
if(toolSetDto.tool2 != null) {
    tool2Dto = toolDescriptionRepository.updateOrSaveNewTool(toolSetDto.getTool2());
}

// New session ..
session = Hibernate.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
tool1 = session.get(Tool.class, tool1Dto.getId());
tool2 = session.get(Tool.class, tool2Dto.getId());
toolSet.setTool1(tool1);
toolSet.setTool2(tool2);
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

and for `updateOrSaveNewTool(ToolDTO toolDto)` we'd have something like:

```
Session session = Hibernate.openSession();
Tool tool = null;

if(toolDto.getId() != null) {
  // Tool does already exist..
  tool = session.get(Tool.class, toolDto.getId());
} else {
  // Store a new tool ..
  session.beginTransaction();
  tool = new Tool();
  session.save(tool);
  ToolDescription toolDescription = new ToolDescription(tool, getDefaultLanguage());
  session.save(toolDescription);
  session.getTransaction().commit();
}

session.close();
```

This would open multiple sessions in one RPC call e.g. Due to my issues I am having [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367765/hibernate-strange-behavior-second-commit-in-another-session-needed-to-acces) I am not sure if I am supposed to do that. *Can I get Caching problems for example?*

Can somebody explain to me how exactly to use Hibernate sessions? I know, they are supposed to execute/handle a unit of work but that does not explain if I should open multiple sessions per request.

I could of course *un*capsulate `updateOrSaveNewTool()` and work e.g. with the raw entity-objects and would not have to perform another `get(Tool.class, tool1Dto.getId())` after `updateOrSaveNewTool()` but this would not be very object oriented ..

Answer (score 1):

A Hibernate session should be seen as "unit of work". If your unit of work involves creating some entities and later consuming them, it would be better to use a single session for all those operations. Even better, you'd have those into a single transaction, so that if one step fails, the previous steps are rolled back. *Usually*, an unit of work is whatever happens inside a single request.

What you are seeing is a common issue, which is solved differently depending on your technology stack.

If you are in a Java EE container, such as Wildfly, you can let the container manage the entity manager for you. So, you just inject an EntityManager which is ready to use (ie: the "session" is already opened for you and will close when you don't need it anymore).

Another common approach is to use one session per request, managed by yourself: you'd have a filter (or something similar) that would open a session once the request is received, and close when the response was ready. You'd store this in a thread local, so that each request would have its own session.

And finally, if you are using Spring, you can delegate the maintenance of the EntityManager to it, like you'd do with a Java EE container.

Comment: So what that means is that I shouldn't have encapsulated the saving of a Tool and ToolDescription entity and reuse them later in another session in the same request but instead do the whole thing just in *one* request/session, right? Because there would be the option to pass an open session to each function call of a repository ([repository pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/526874/Repositorypluspattern-cplusdoneplusright)) just to enure that all action occur in just one pre-opened session.

Comment: The question is in that case if the Repository-Pattern as such is okay with that - I am not sure about that but maybe that's another question.

Comment: Yes, you *could*, but I don't think you'd want to do that. I'm quite sure that whatever environment you are deploying your application might already have a good solution for your problem. The exception would be a "standalone" client, ie, not deployed in any container.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you stop writing your own session and transaction management code, and instead use standard solutions like Spring which will do all of this for you.

Read about Spring Hibernate support [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html).
Read about Spring transaction management [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html).

When set up, your code will look like this:

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Transactional
public void foo() {
  tool1 = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Tool.class, tool1Dto.getId());
  toolSet.setTool1(tool1);
  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(tool1);
}
```

Comment: That's a good hint but unfortunately does not really answer my question there. How would that look like in my scenario where I have to "pre-store" some entities before being able to store my `ToolSet`. I just don't know how I am supposed to do that here.

Comment: Okay agree. Hibernate.openSession() will always open a new session, so like you indicate this can be impractical if you operate on the same objects in two different sessions. You should rather use sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(), which returns a session bound to a context (and does not need to be closed). By default the context is bound to the current thread, so normally this means the session will be reused across all your methods. That is why i suggested using Spring with sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() - it will automatically reuse the session across all calls in the request.